# Autocomplete functionality not working correctly

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css

so I'm making this functionality in which I've used jQuery Autocomplete to fetch data from a database, and display it in the search box.
Everything works completely fine, but when I hover over the results (in the dropdown, it displays the number pertaining to the result).
Instead, it should show the result name.
Here's an image attached :-
[image: Test Image]

In the above image, it shows the number **4** for **Apple Mac**, instead, it should show **Apple Mac** when I *point / hover* over that.
How can I fix this ?

jQuery Code :-

```
<script>
  $(function() {
    function log( message ) {
      $( "<div>" ).text( message ).prependTo( "#log" );
      $( "#log" ).scrollTop( 0 );
    }

    $( "#birds" ).autocomplete({
      source: "search.php",
      minLength: 2,
      select: function( event, ui ) {


        log( ui.item ? "Selected: " + ui.item.value + " aka " + ui.item.label :
          "Nothing selected, input was " + this.actor );
         window.location.href = './products/' + ui.item.value;
         //window.location.href = 'product_display.php?id=' + ui.item.value;
       // document.testForm.action = "pretravel.php?id="+ui.item.value;
        //document.testForm.submit();
      }
    });
  });



  </script>
```

**Search.php**

```
<?php
include 'dbconnector.php';

// Sanitise GET var
if(isset($_GET['term']))
{
$term = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['term']);
// Add WHERE clause
//$term="Apple";
$query = "SELECT `productid`, `productname` FROM `products` WHERE `productname` LIKE '%".$term."%' ORDER BY `productid`";


$result = mysql_query($query,$db) or die (mysql_error($db));
$id=0;
$return=array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){

    //array_push($return,array('label'=>$row['productid'],'actor'=>$row['productname']));
    array_push($return,array('value'=>$row['productid'],'label'=>$row['productname']));
    //array_push($return,array('actor'=>$row['productname'],'label'=>$row['productid']));

}

header('Content-type: application/json');
echo json_encode($return);
//var_dump($return);

exit(); // AJAX call, we don't want anything carrying on here
}
else
{
    header('Location:index');
}

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not confuse autocomplete-enabled text inputs with a select inputs. A text input can only contain a single value, it's text value. Therefore, instead of passing the id back to javascript, just pass the name of each result and use that as both the label and the value.

```
 array_push($return,array('label'=>$row['productname']));
```

this of course makes other parts of your workflow more difficult, such as your redirect based on product id instead of product name, so i'd suggest continuing to return the productid, just not as value.

```
 array_push($return,array('productid'=>$row['productid'],'label'=>$row['productname']));
```

now you can access the productid in the event.

```
window.location.href = './products/' + ui.item.productid;
```

Answer (score 1):

The auto complete isn't working because you are returning both id and values from your call. One option is to only return the value. Alternatively, if you need both the id and the value, you will want to look at overriding the select routine for auto complete. On the jQuery web site you can see an example here: http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#custom-data. The relevant code is:

```
$( "#project" ).autocomplete({
  minLength: 0,
  source: projects,
  focus: function( event, ui ) {
    $( "#project" ).val( ui.item.label );
    return false;
  },
  select: function( event, ui ) {
    $( "#project" ).val( ui.item.label );
    $( "#project-id" ).val( ui.item.value );
    $( "#project-description" ).html( ui.item.desc );
    $( "#project-icon" ).attr( "src", "images/" + ui.item.icon );

    return false;
  }
})
.data( "ui-autocomplete" )._renderItem = function( ul, item ) {
  return $( "<li>" )
    .append( "<a>" + item.label + "<br>" + item.desc + "</a>" )
    .appendTo( ul );
};
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

just return the product name only. make it as label and value

array_push($return,array('value'=>$row['productname'],'label'=>$row['productname']));